# Raspberry PI Pico USB Connection Issues when configuring/setting up ports

Tags: c, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using the USB port of the Raspberry Pi Pico as my debug port when running C programs on the Pico. I have noticed that sometimes when I connect to the Pico USB using Putty in serial port mode, it takes forever (at least 5min) to connect and display the Putty terminal window. I have done the following to eliminate this issue:

1. Multiple reboots of the Pico before I am able to connect immediately.
2. Removing Pin configuration and initialization code eg: gpio_init(2); gpio_set_dir(2, GPIO_OUT); and so on. I noticed when doing this I connect immediately. Put this code back and I am back to waiting 5min for Putty to connect or resetting the device multiple times.
   Does anybody know why this is happening?

Many Thanks.

Comment: edit the Q to reflect the code you are using and any wiring you have done

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.